# Log of local undo's using TFS

Tags: tfs

Here I am on Monday morning and a file I spent 15+ hours on last week, looks like I have lost my changes. I am going to guess that on Friday afternoon I accidentally undid changes on the file but I'm not sure. I know it's a long shot but any way to "undo" an undo? Is there a log stored locally on my computer that will tell me if I did undo the changes to that specific file? I checked the history on the file and I did not accidentally check it in.

Comment: Have you already found an solution for this or have you lost your work like the answers said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to undo an undo. In the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245456%28VS.80%29.aspx) you can read the following:

> If you undo an edit, your copy of the file is **replaced** with an unmodified version of the file you checked out

So you are overwriting the file. More information about the undo command can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c72skhw4%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm pretty sure you are out of luck. When you perform an undo your local changes are written over with the latest from the server.